# Spring Data JPA to Spring Data Redis - what all changes are needed?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-redis

I am new to Redis and trying to implement change Postgres DB into the Redis DB. Current implementation we've used Spring Data JPA (Entity Classes + JPA Repository). Now I wanted to use Spring Data Redis and backend as Redis In Memory DB.

Could you please suggest what changes do I need to make in all Entity classes ? How the persistence will happen ? Do I need to make any changes in Join Table etc.. where I have `@ManyToOne` and `@ManyToMany` relationship.

Comment: Redis is not a database like Postgres which is a great choice. What are your reasons to switch to Redis and lose all the benefits of a RDBMS. Usually you would use Redis to compliment Postgres.

Comment: @ Chirdeep Tomar - Actually we've static data - around 20 table, 5K to 7K records only .. For that reason we're planning to move to redis. Could you please suggest further ?

Answer (score 0):

Redis a nosql solution so you will not get the befit of foreign keys as in a RDBMS. You will instead need to convert you data into data-structures supported by Redis. https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Comment: Would you like to share example either using One to Many and manyToMany example conversion to redis?

Comment: @Sayali you are missing the point, there is no OneToMany or ManyToMany relationship in Redis, you need to forget thinking in terms of relationships. Look at Hashes datatype in Redis for example, you can create a key with multiple values inside it, that will give you a similar behaviour like OneToMany.

Comment: Thanks thats what I am asking you. How to convert those relationship into the (modify schema) to accommodate into redis ?